# How to play video and audio extracted from mkv file in metro app

Tags: mediaelement, decoder, mkv

I have managed to read matroska container and able to extract video and audio streams from a mkv file in my metro app. Now, I don't know how to feed the streams for playing. I want to know the concept of throwing media data on display. I have another option to repack the video and audio(s) with subtitles into MP4 container which will be played by MediaElement by default but that will not look like having a matroska codec in my metro app.

So, basically my question is: How to use MediaElement or any display graph to read the video and audio pulled out from any video container.

Please guide me. Thanks.